# Importing osm planet file to PostGIS after osm2pgsql couldn't commit due to connection timed out

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I wanted to know if there was a way to import a node.cache file, containing a planet file, after osm2pgsql has crashed because of connection timed out error?

I don't want to launch again the tool and wait for the full extraction to run once more. I used the `--slim` mode with the `--flat-nodes` mode and provided a location where to store the node.cache file. It was created nicely but during the commit to database phase, osm2pgsql throws an error because the connection timed out.

I'm using : PostgreSQL 9.6.5 | PostGIS 2.4.0 | Debian Stretch

Here's the verbose output of the tool :

```
user@woopdidoo:~$ osm2pgsql -c -H host -P port -d postgres -U postgres -W --slim -C 4608 --flat-nodes node.cache ways_north_america.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql version 0.92.0 (64 bit id space)

Password:
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=4608MB, maxblocks=73728*65536, allocation method=11
Mid: loading persistent node cache from node.cache
Allocated space for persistent node cache file
Maximum node in persistent node cache: 0
Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=4608
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: ways_north_america.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
Processing: Node(199609k 364.9k/s) Way(20842k 11.98k/s) Relation(80 80.00/s)Maximum node in persistent node cache: 5234491391
node cache: stored: 199609351(100.00%), storage efficiency: 61.93% (dense blocks: 20221, sparse nodes: 78339611), hit rate: 100.00%
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: could not send data to server: Connection timed out
: relations_set - bad result during COPY, data 11723    0   83  {20800929,20801040,20801184,20801189,20801313,20801364,20801453,20801519,20801570,20801624,20801640,20801676,20801852,20801875,20801917,20802267,20802317,20802424,20802463,20802520,20802543,20802761,20802944,20802951,20802958,20803092,20803166,20803257,20803280,20803571,20803629,20803723,20803870,20804078,20804110,20804124,20804170,20804228,20804374,20804721,20804722,20804767,20804781,20804890,20804916,20805056,20805107,20805258,20805262,20805268,20805310,20805314,20805436,20805495,20805504,20805517,20805530,20805609,20805637,20805730,20805732,20805801,20805849,20805937,20806035,20806168,20806224,20806258,20806407,20806490,20806549,20806696,20806883,20807012,20807025,20807079,20807207,20807246,20807337,20807386,24016842,24016843,24250860}    {"w20800929","inner","w20801040","inner","w20801184","inner","w20801189","inner","w20801313","inner","w20801364","inner","w20801453","inner","w20801519","inner","w20801570","inner","w20801624","inner","w20801640","inner","w20801676","inner","w20801852","inner","w20801875","inner","w20801917","inner","w20802267","inner","w20802317","inner","w20802424","inner","w20802463","inner","w20802520","inner","w20802543","inner","w20802761","inner","w20802944","inner","w20802951","inner","w20802958","inner","w20803092","inner","w20803166","inner","w20803257","inner","w20803280","inner","w20803571","inner","w20803629","inner","w20803723","inner","w20803870","inner","w20804078","inner","w20804110","inner","w20804124","inner","w20804170","inner","w20804228","inner","w20804374","inner","w20804721","inner","w20804722","inner","w20804767","inner","w20804781","inner","w20804890","inner","w20804916","inner","w20805056","inner","w20805107","inner","w20805258","inner","w20805262","inner","w20805268","inner","w20805310","inner","w20805314","inner","w20805436","inner","w20805495","inner","w20805504","inner","w20805517","inner","w20805530","inner","w20805609","inner","w20805637","inner","w20805730","inner","w20805732","inner","w20805801","inner","w20805849","inner","w20805937","inner","w20806035","inner","w20806168","inner","w20806224","inner","w20806258","inner","w20806407","inner","w20806490","inner","w20806549","inner","w20806696","inner","w20806883","inner","w20807012","inner","w20807025","inner","w20807079","inner","w20807207","inner","w20807246","inner","w20807337","inner","w20807386","inner","w24016842","inner","w24016843","inner","w24250860","outer"}   {"type","multipolygon","waterway","riverbank"}
```